# Spacing between html ruler and text above

Tags: html

I have the following code:

```
    <p><font size='5'><b>Loop Main</b></font><br><HR align='left' WIDTH='60%'></p>
```

The problem is that under Loop Main, I get some spacing and then the HR show up. Is there a way to get the 
ruler right underneath the text without any spacing between them?

Comment: Do you know what CSS is? When not you should read / learn about it. Because the code you are giving us comes straight from the 80's.

Comment: @S.Visser, he probably doesn't. No need to be rude.

Comment: @JakeParis can you tell me whats rude in my comment? I do not mean it rude, just saying that the code he showing us comes from the time that the internet was born ( all the attributes and elements comming from the first w3 html version ).

Comment: @S.Visser "time the internet was born" :D  That's awesome (and true).

Comment: Guys: you are making assumptions about this person... for all you know Nate could be 8 years old or 90 and just writing their first webpage, or somebody who's just lost their job as an awesome craftsperson trying out IT for the first time... who knows? there may be any number of very good reasons for Nate not already being familiar with CSS and making comments like "No no no, this is not the way to do it" or "Do you even know what CSS is"* are not necessary... just be helpful and explain why we use CSS now :) *(yes I changed the wording to show you why it sounds a little rude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use css. And yes, you can acheive what you would like.

```css
p.main {
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
hr {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top:0;
  }
```

```html
<p class="main">Loop Main</p>
<hr>
```

If you would like the `<hr>` up even closer to the text, you will have to use positioning, like so:

```css
p.main {
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
hr {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top:0;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  }
```

```html
<p class="main">Loop Main</p>
<hr>
```

Of course, probably even a better solution is just to put a border-bottom on the `<p>` like:

```css
p.main {
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<p class="main">Loop Main</p>
```

Answer (score -3):

you could try something like

```
<HR align='left' Width='60%' style='margin-top: -3px;' />
```

or you could use css to change the line height property of the HTML `<p>` attribute